# Adding style to Dynamic Button

Tags: wpf

I have adding Button to UI like this:

```
Button objBTN = new Button();
objBTN.Content = "Test";
grid.Children.Add(objBTN);
```

How could I set style like this to button

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="OrangeButtons" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Grid>
        <Border x:Name="border"   Background="White" BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="5,5,5,5" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
        </Border>
        <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  FontSize="15"/>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="#FFFFC934"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming that "OrangeButtons" is declared in Resources, use `FindResource` method to get it in code and then apply to button:

```
Button objBTN = new Button
{
   Content = "Test",
   Template = (ControlTemplate)grid.FindResource("OrangeButtons")
};
grid.Children.Add(objBTN);
```